# Spaces in the button causes the button to make a new line in the Navbar

Tags: html, css, button, navbar

When adding a space in the button's text, it causes the navbar to create a new line

The Navbar code, all the CSS is manually added (Uses Bootstrap)

```
    <img src="images/SCP_Logo.jpg" style='width: 100%; max-width:100%;'>
        
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" >SCP Foundation</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
```

Button that causes issues

```
        <button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech() " class="btn navButton" style="margin-left: 1%;"> TextToSpeech </button>
```

```
<button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech() " class="btn navButton" style="margin-left: 1%;"> Pause </button>
    
<button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech() " class="btn navButton" style="margin-left: 1%;"> Stop </button>


</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not easy to understand, but I tried to create a snippet for you below and cleaned up your code a bit.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```html
<img src="images/SCP_Logo.jpg" style='width: 100%; max-width:100%;'>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
   <a class="navbar-brand" >SCP Foundation</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Your problem button</span>
   </button>
   <button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech() " class="btn navButton" style="margin-left: 1%;"> Pause </button>
   <button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech() " class="btn navButton" style="margin-left: 1%;"> Stop </button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your problem button with

```html
<button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech() " class="btn navButton" style="margin-left: 1%; width: 200px;">The Problem Button</button>
```

You can play around with the `width:200px` style and adjust it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out my issue, so what was happening was when I wrote a margin-left within the button to move the buttons from each other, but with removing the margin-left this has fixed it

Issue was that the margin-left was forcing the word to the next line.

```
<button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech() " class="btn navButton" > TextToSpeech </button>
```